# Multiple Class Java error: Ljava.lang.String

Tags: java, class

I have to make 2 classes (Course.java and UseCourse.java). I have to have methods like get course, courseName, addStudent, dropStudent, getStudent and getNumberOfStudent.

When I tried to run these files I keep getting:

**3 students are in Java Programming : [Ljava.lang.String; @6bc7c054**

Can somebody explain what this means and how I can fix it?

UseCourse.java

```
public class UseCourse{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Course c1 = new Course("Java Programming", "Bob Brown");

        c1.getCourseName();
        c1.getStudents();
        c1.getNumberOfStudents();

        System.out.println(c1.numberOfStudents + " students are in "+
        c1.courseName + " : " + c1.students);

        //c1.dropStudent("Andrew Drew");
        c1.getStudents();
        c1.getNumberOfStudents();
        System.out.println(c1.numberOfStudents + " students are in "+
        c1.courseName + " : " + c1.students);
    }
}
```

Course.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.String;

public class Course{
    String courseName;
    String[] students = {"Berry Cherry", "Lia Lee", "Andrew Drew"};
    int numberOfStudents;

    Course(String newCourseName, String newAddStudent){
        courseName = newCourseName;

// Not sure if I'm doing this right but I'm trying to 
// add the new student to the end of the list/array

        students[students.length -1] = newAddStudent; 
    }

    /*public void dropStudent{

    }*/

    public String getCourseName(){
        return courseName;
    }

    public String getStudents(){
        return Arrays.toString(students);
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents(){
        numberOfStudents = students.length;
        return numberOfStudents;
    }
}
```

Comment: [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](//stackoverflow.com/a/409795)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because this is the default textual representation of an Array (`toString`)

So use this : `Arrays.toString(students)`

```java
System.out.println(c1.numberOfStudents + " students are in "+
        c1.courseName + " : " + Arrays.toString(c1.students));
```

Comment: Do you mean here: public String getStudents(){
        return Arrays.toString(students);
    }